# Cannot get list for dropdownfor (to edit model)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, selectlist

I am creating a form to post edits back to the controller and have a few drop downs in the controller.  I have tried two different ways that are not working in the view.  This is what I tried first:

```
@Html.DropDownList("TechnicianId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Now I am trying this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TechnicianId, ViewBag.TechnicianId)
```

and this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TechnicianId, TechnicianId)
```

from what I look online the second or third one are the closest. However it is not coming up as a list.  Here is the code I have in the controller:

```
ViewBag.TechnicianId = new SelectList(db.Users.Where(u => u.Status == 1 || u.RoleID == new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")), "UserId", "FullName");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression in DropDownListFor should identify the object that contains the properties to display.

Try having users in the TechnicianId list:

```
ViewBag.TechnicianId = db.Users
       .Where(u => u.Status == 1 || 
                   u.RoleID == new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));
```

And then in the view:

```
<%=Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TechnicianId, 
                             new SelectList(
                                 ViewBag.TechnicianId, 
                                 "Value", 
                                 "Key")) %>
```

Comment: Thank you that has got me half way there but when I post the form back, I keep getting this error on that line in the view: "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: You have one of your arguments as null. Look at the stack trace for more details.

Comment: After looking at it the Viewbag.TechnicianId is coming up as Null. In the HTTPGet method it is coming up with a value but then once I click the Update button it goes null. Do I need to put that line of code somewhere else?

Comment: Never Mind I figured it out.